# how to display greek chars read from textfile?

Tags: python-3.x, pygtk

It is easy to print greek in a string:

```
my_str = "Grec ancien : \u03ad\u03cd\u03bb\u03bf\u03b3\u03bf\u03bd \u03ad\u03be\u03b1\u03c9\u03b3\u03ae\u03bd."
```

and then:

> `print(my_str)`
>   gives the desired result:

```
Grec ancien : έύλογον έξαωγήν.
```

However, if the above string is in a text file (e.g., data0.txt), the print method doesn't yield a satisfactory result:

```
with open('page0.txt') as f:
...   for line in f:
...     print(line)
... 
Grec ancien : \u03ad\u03cd\u03bb\u03bf\u03b3\u03bf\u03bd \u03ad\u03be\u03b1\u03c9\u03b3\u03ae\u03bd.
```

Why is this?